# Less compiler doesn't update css file after LESS code is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, font-awesome

This is way beyond my knowledge..
I was migrating my rails 3 application from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. I downloaded Bootstrap 3 and FontAwesome, put them into my assets folder. Then I tried to modify the font path. I change @FontAwesomePath in font-awesome/variables.less several times, however it still don't points to the correct path. (I put font files in ./app/assets/fonts/font-awesome/)

```
    @FontAwesomePath:    "fonts/font-awesome"
```

It's ok, cuz I saw the line below this one is a cdn path to font files:

```
    //@FontAwesomePath:    "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/font"; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
```

I uncomment this line, everything seems fine. The compiled css file load the font from cdn and all icons are displaying.

Then I delete this line, try to point @FontAwesomePath back to local server again. STRANGE thing happened! No matter what I did, the compiled css file points it to the CDN path! I tried to clear browser cache, reboot rails server (I was using development mode of rails server), even to load the website from other computers, nothing changes. It insisting point @FontAwesomePath to the CDN path even no where in the whole application code exists the url! I can only image there is some kind of variable cache in less compiler. Can anybody tell me what's happened inside this? It's driven me crazy.

edit: I'm using less gem (v 2.3.2), which includes lesscss v 1.3.3.

Comment: in the `rails console` try `Rails.cache.clear`, and then restart the server. For the path, try setting it to `assets/fonts/font-awesome`

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with CSS updates, these where only solved by going to tmp > cache and deleting the assets folder then restarting the server. The CSS was then updated.
Hope this helps.
Steph

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue on my local machine. Even after saving, hard refreshing browser changes of `less` was not reflecting.

**Configuration-**
`Ubuntu 20.04`
`ruby 2.7.1p83`
`Rails 6.1.7.2`

**Solution:**

1. Stop runing rails server
2. Run `rake tmp:cache:clear` command into terminal
3. Restart rails server again
4. Hard refresh browser page
   It worked for me!!!